# Rails searchkick gem, show the distance between two points

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchkick

I'm using the `searchkick gem` on my app in order to get results by distance:

```
@items = Item.search params[:search], page: params[:page], per_page: 10, fields: [:title], match: :phrase, location: {near: {lat: origin[0], lon: origin[1]}, within: within}}, order: {_geo_distance: {location: "#{destination[0]},#{destination[1]}", order: "asc", unit: unit} }
```

As you can see `searchkick` will calculate the distance between two points, the origin and the destination and return the results according to the closets one.

Now if I loop through the `@item.each do |item|` is there a way to show the calculated distance number between those two points? Is there a `searchkick param` I can access?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take advantage of `#each_with_hit` here:

```
@items.each_with_hit do |item, hit|
  p hit
end
```

([Source](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick/issues/73#issuecomment-29915098))

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Scott Matthewman, unfortunately I get and error: `undefined method each_with_hit for <Searchkick::Results:0x007fef0f884dd8>Did you mean?  each_with_index`... if I change to `<% @items.each_with_index do |item, hit|%>` I get 0 for `<%= hit %>` Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! That's an out of date API method. The new syntax is apparently `@items.with_hit.each`. Try that, and if it works I'll update the answer to keep SO up to date.

Comment: This time it doesn't give an error but it returns this `{"_index"=>"items_development_20181104141312240", "_type"=>"item", "_id"=>"1", "_score"=>nil, "sort"=>[0.6180733141351362]}` for this `<%= hit %>`

Comment: even if I  do this `<%= hit.sort %>`

Comment: any ideas why this is showing `{"_index"=>"items_development_20181104141312240", "_type"=>"item", "_id"=>"1", "_score"=>nil, "sort"=>[0.6180733141351362]}` for this `<%= hit %>` ?? I still can't figure this one out!